# Javascript variable comparison

Tags: javascript

I have javascript with global variable declared:

```
var IsUserAllowed = false;
```

And I have a function:

```
function setSelectedIdsInput(inputLogicalId) {
   if (IsUserAllowed) {
```

This does not work, I assume the value of IsUserAllowed  is in string.
So i did:

```
var isUserAllowedStr = IsUserAllowed.toString().toLowerCase();
if (isUserAllowedStr == "true") {
```

This works, Since im new to java script i wanted to know if its ok to compare strings like this.
This due to fact that doing:

```
if (isUserAllowedStr.localeCompare("true")) {
```

Did not work either !

Thanks!

**Update** - i suspect the global var was string and not Boolean. this why the if failed. when i did alert(IsUserAllowed) the output was "False"

Comment: What do you mean by "This does not work"? If `IsUserAllowed` is set to false, doing `if(IsUserAllowed)` obviously isn't going to evaluate to true.

Comment: The first one should work fine. Run a log statement before the `if`

Comment: if (IsUserAllowed) -- this ONLY works if IsUserAllowed is a boolean TRUE, in your case, since it's false, you may rather check: if (!IsUserAllowed). Also, instead of parsing the string, try to use the === operator.

Comment: in this case you better ask what you want to know not to show us what doesn't do work

Comment: Stating simply, "does not work" without any details makes for a bad question. Describe what you expect to happen and what you observe actually happening.

Comment: It was false, and still got inside the If !!! I used alertalert(IsUserAllowed) - this showed false ! and still went inside the if !!

Comment: @ilansch that would be impossible, but you have not yet posted enough code for anyone to explain what's wrong.

Comment: It was false, how do i know if this variable is boolean or string ? in run time, i suspect this var to be string and not bool. maybe the if () failed since the var is string and not bool. when i printed i got "False" as output

Comment: @ilansch You can use `alert(typeof IsUserAllowed);` to see the type of the variable. If it is the string `"false"` then `if(IsUserAllowed)` would evaluate to true (JavaScript considers any non-empty string to be true when performing type conversion). However, rather than using a workaround you should be fixing the issue that's causing it to change from a boolean (when you first declare it) to a string when you actually come to test it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thank you for working with me on this one, as I mentioned i am noob to javascript, i did what you said, it returned me "string" in the alert. the type was as i suspect - string and not bool, So what is the proper way of comparing strings ? is "==" ok ?

Comment: @ilansch You should probably use `===` so it doesn't do any type conversion (i.e. it only returns true if both sides are strings, and the contents of those strings are the same). However, as I already said, that's not the correct course of action: find out why `IsUserAllowed` isn't a boolean and fix that so that it is.

Comment: Ofcourse I will. this is a code i maintain, find bugs and fix, later on i do architecture fixes

Answer (score 1):

```
var IsUserAllowed = false;
```

then

```
function setSelectedIdsInput(inputLogicalId) {
   if (IsUserAllowed) {
       // something true
   } else {
       // something false
   }
```

or

```
if(IsUserAllowed === true)
```

but it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (isUserAllowed === true) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isUserAllowed is a boolean (`true` / `false`):

You can check it by simply doing

```
if (isUserAllowed) { }
```

Or

```
if (isUserAllowed === true) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work as expected.
You can play around in this JSFiddle to test for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/bT8hV/

```
var IsUserAllowed = false;
function setSelectedIdsInput() {
  if (IsUserAllowed) {
    alert('TRUE');
  }
  else {
    alert('FALSE');
  }
};
setSelectedIdsInput();
```